# Nestjs class validator dto validate body parameters

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, class-validator

Hey guys i have a DTO for validate body parameters. For example;

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class RejectChecklistDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiProperty({
    example: '62d7c686b6c7ed853a33adcc',
    description: 'Checklist ID',
  })
  _id: string;
}
```

I am sending a post request in this method like this;

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "test" : ""
}
```

The problem here is that class validator accepts it. I want to throw BadRequest or something because test is not defined in dto. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you may used in main.ts

whitelist: boolean

If set to true, validator will strip validated (returned) object of any properties that do not use any validation decorators.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
```

forbidNonWhitelisted: boolean

If set to true, instead of stripping non-whitelisted properties validator will throw an exception.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ forbidNonWhitelisted: true }));
```

forbidUnknownValues: boolean

If set to true, attempts to validate unknown objects fail immediately.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ forbidUnknownValues: true }));
```

Comment: thanks `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ forbidNonWhitelisted: true }));` thats what im talking about

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to main.ts

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true}));
```

it won't throw any error but it will just discard all the values which are not in dto

Comment: I add this and i am add a middleware for log and console.log result like this ; 
``
/check-list/reject { _id: '62e92cfe39e23642746f7447', test: ''" }
``
its still same

Comment: can you share the controller function and the decorators you are using with it

Comment: `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ forbidNonWhitelisted: true }));` 
This solved my problem thanks